# Verilog carry lookahead adder

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

```
`timescale 100ns/1ps

module CarryLAS_tb;

reg [7:0] a;
reg [7:0] b;
reg ci;

wire [7:0] sum;
wire of; //overflow
wire co;

integer i;

CarryLAS_8 CLA(a,b,ci,sum,co,of);   



initial begin 

a=0;
b=0;
ci=0;

end


initial begin // all possible cases 

for(i=0; i<262144; i=i+1) // 2^18


#10 {a, b, ci} = i;


end

endmodule

module CarryLAS_8(a,b,ci,sum,co,of);

input [7:0] a,b;

input ci; // 0; Add 1: Subtract

output [7:0] sum;
output co;
output of;

wire[7:0] c;

wire[7:0] xb;

xor(xb[0],b[0],ci);

xor(xb[1],b[1],ci);

xor(xb[2],b[2],ci);

xor(xb[3],b[3],ci);

xor(xb[4],b[4],ci);

xor(xb[5],b[5],ci);

xor(xb[6],b[6],ci);

xor(xb[7],b[7],ci);

xor(of,c[7],c[6]);

xor(co,c[7],ci);

CarryLA_8 CLAS(a,xb,ci,sum,co);


endmodule


module CarryLA_8(a,b,ci,sum,co);

input [7:0] a,b;
input ci;

output [7:0] sum;
output co;

wire [7:0] sum;
wire cm,co;

CarryLA_4 CLA0(a[3:0],b[3:0],ci,sum[3:0],cm);
CarryLA_4 CLA1(a[7:4],b[7:4],cm,sum[7:4],cm);

endmodule


module CarryLA_4(a,b,ci,sum,co);

input [3:0] a,b;

input ci; // 0; Add 1: Subtract

output [3:0] sum;

output co;

wire[3:0] g,p,cout;
wire G0,P0;
wire[9:0] w;

and a0(g[0],a[0],b[0]); 
and a1(g[1],a[1],b[1]); 
and a2(g[2],a[2],b[2]); 
and a3(g[3],a[3],b[3]); 


xor x0(p[0],a[0],b[0]);
xor x1(p[1],a[1],b[1]);
xor x2(p[2],a[2],b[2]);
xor x3(p[3],a[3],b[3]);

and and0(w[0],p[0],ci);
or or0(cout[0],g[0],w[0]);

and and1(w[1],p[1],p[0],ci);
and and2(w[2],p[1],g[0]);
or or1(cout[1],g[1],w[2],w[1]);

and and3(w[3],p[2],p[1],p[0],ci);
and and4(w[4],p[2],p[1],g[0]);
and and5(w[5],p[2],g[1]);
or or2(cout[2],g[2],w[5],w[4],w[3]);

and and6(w[6],p[3],p[2],p[1],g[0]);
and and7(w[7],p[3],p[2],g[1]);
and and8(g[2],a[2],b[2]); 
or or3(G0,g[3],w[8],w[7],w[6]);

and and9(P0,p[3],p[2],p[1],p[0]);

and and10(w[9],P0,ci);
or or4(cout[3],G0,w[9]);

and and11(co,cout[3],1);

xor xor0(sum[0],p[0],ci);
xor xor1(sum[1],p[1],cout[0]);
xor xor2(sum[2],p[2],cout[1]);
xor xor3(sum[3],p[3],cout[2]);



endmodule
```

This is my Verilog code. simulated well, but the result kinda sucks. 
'sum' produces values with some Xs, and 'co', 'of'(overflow detection) are also Xs. I couldn't find out what the problem is. It might be about carry I think.
Could anyone help me with this?
Any help would be really appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Captured waveform is attached

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAZ8T.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fy1Tt.png)

Comment: oh I never know about that site. I used modelsim to simulate it , and it didn't seem to offer simulation error info.

Comment: I think the fourth carry bit from the MSB is the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple drivers on `wire [8:0] c`.  In your generate you have:

```
or o1 (c[i+1],g[i],q[i]);
```

and then you have the FullAdder instances that drive c:

```
FullAdder a0(a[0],b[0],ci,sum[0],c[0]);
```

I can't be certain that this is the reason that it won't simulate, but it certainly will make it not function correctly.

Answer (score 0):

you should change "initial" part of your testbench like this:

```
initial 
begin 
assign ci =0;

assign a=8'b00000001;
assign b=8'b00000001;

#20
assign a=8'b00010010;
assign b=8'b00110111;

#20
assign a=8'b01011100;
assign b=8'b10010001;

#20
$finish;
```

and little wrong in module CarryLA_4 :

```
module CarryLA_4(a,b,ci,sum,co);

input [3:0] a,b;
input ci; 

output [3:0] sum;
output co;

wire[3:0] g,p,cout;
wire G0,P0;
wire[9:0] w;

and a0(g[0],a[0],b[0]); 
and a1(g[1],a[1],b[1]); 
and a2(g[2],a[2],b[2]); 
and a3(g[3],a[3],b[3]); 

xor x0(p[0],a[0],b[0]);
xor x1(p[1],a[1],b[1]);
xor x2(p[2],a[2],b[2]);
xor x3(p[3],a[3],b[3]);

and and0(w[0],p[0],ci);
or or0(cout[0],g[0],w[0]);

and and1(w[1],p[1],p[0],ci);
and and2(w[2],p[1],g[0]);
or or1(cout[1],g[1],w[2],w[1]);

and and3(w[3],p[2],p[1],p[0],ci);
and and4(w[4],p[2],p[1],g[0]);
and and5(w[5],p[2],g[1]);
or or2(cout[2],g[2],w[5],w[4],w[3]);

and and6(w[6],p[3],p[2],p[1],g[0]);
and and7(w[7],p[3],p[2],g[1]);
and and8(w[8],p[3],p[2],p[1],p[0],ci);
and and9(w[9],p[3],g[2]);
or or3(cout[3],g[3],w[9],w[8],w[7],w[6]);

and and10(co,cout[3],1);

xor xor0(sum[0],p[0],ci);
xor xor1(sum[1],p[1],cout[0]);
xor xor2(sum[2],p[2],cout[1]);
xor xor3(sum[3],p[3],cout[2]);

endmodule
```